# Cortana Dashboard Not Loading

Tags: cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I am trying to access my Cortana skill from the Cortana Dashboard (http://aka.ms/cortana-skills). I used to be able to get to here from the bot framework page and add/remove users to the skill. Right now all I get is a blank page with no skills listed. Is anyone else experiencing this or is there another way to manage your Cortana skills ?[image: Cortana dashboard]

Comment: I have the exact same, filed a ticket through the support option.

Comment: Just received response from support. Because this is a preview, we're not getting any support and they redirected me here, to SO. So much for that option....

Comment: Hi @Jasper and rustyocean, there is an issue with accessing the Cortana Dashboard via the Bot Framework portal that the dev team is currently looking into.

Comment: Thanks @StevenG., looking forward to the solution. Keep us posted please :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this. It appears to be fixed. Can you confirm. If it doesn't look like it is working, try ctrl+F5 to see if that helps.

Comment: Nope it's not fixed. There's two JavaScript error in my console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" and "Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/unpr?p0=userServiceProvider%20%3C-%20userService"

Comment: Can you try again. Looks like the fix wasn't rolled out completely to all data centers. Should be resolved now.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed now

Comment: Confirmed, fixed for me too.